# Calculate Days, Hours and minutes between two different dates and times

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I have a SharePoint list with two date columns. I want to create calculated column which gives the number of days, hours and minutes between these two dates.

I have looked at all possible threads, but the DATEDIF function does not work.

```
=DATEDIF([A],[B],"D")
=DATEDIF([A],[B];"D")
=DATEDIF([B],[A],"D")
=DATEDIF([B],[A];"D")
```

No combination with DATEDIF works.

Below formula is ok but without Days because shows a strange value

```
=TEXT(B-A;"d hh:mm")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With combination of MOD() and TEXT() functions we can accomplish this.
Try the below formula by replacing the actual column names in your list

```
=(((INT(([End Time]-[Start Time])*1440)-MOD(INT(([End Time]-[Start Time])*1440),60))/60)-(MOD((INT(([End Time]-[Start Time])*1440)-MOD(INT(([End Time]-[Start Time])*1440),60))/60,24)))/24&" Days "&MOD((INT(([End Time]-[Start Time])*1440)-MOD(INT(([End Time]-[Start Time])*1440),60))/60,24)&" Hours "&(MOD(INT(([End Time]-[Start Time])*1440),60)+1)&" Minutes"
```

[image]